# IntroJS Conditional Steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, intro.js

I have a form where some of the fields become visible only when a checkbox is checked. I want to walk user through using IntroJS demo.

Is there a way by which I can add conditional steps to Intro JS.

Following is how steps are defined.
Step 4 should only be shown if a particular checkbox is checked.

```
intro.setOptions({
            steps: [
                {
                    intro: "Hi! Lets start personilizing your settings. Click 'Next' to begin."
                },
                {
                    element: document.querySelector('#step1'),
                    intro: "Enter the email address where you would like to receive alerts. (for multiple user semi colon ';' as separator)",
                },
                {
                    element: document.querySelectorAll('#step2')[0],
                    intro: "Select your time zone.",
                    position: 'left'
                },
                {
                    element: '#step3',
                    intro: 'Turn \"On\" to receive payment reminder alerts.',
                    position: 'left'
                },
                {
                    element: '#step4',
                    intro: 'Select a \"Fee Type\". (The setting defines the type of fee to be applied to past due accounts.)'
                }
            ]
        });
```

Comment: Steps accepts JSON objects so you can just dynamically create the JSON object with the steps you want and pass that to steps. Will post an answer when I'm in front of a computer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a JSfiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/rv85ntcv/6/

The key is that you splice the steps array whenever the element is hidden.

```js
var btn1=document.getElementById("step1");
var btn2=document.getElementById("start");
var div=document.getElementById("step2");

btn1.onclick=function(){
if (div.style.display !=="none") {
  div.style.display="none";
} else {
  div.style.display="block";
}
};
// this is the crucial part
btn2.onclick=function(){
 var steps=[
  {element:"#step1",intro:"A button", position:"right"},
 {element:"#step2",intro:"This goes away sometimes"}
  ];
  
  if (div.style.display==="none") {
   steps.splice(1,1);
  }

  introJs().setOptions({
  steps:steps
  }).start();
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usablica/intro.js/master/introjs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/1.0.0/intro.min.js"></script>
<div id="step2">
Some text
</div>

<button id="step1" >
Press me to hide div
</button>

<button id="start" >
Press me to start intro
</button>
```